# Can the Inverse Finding the Laplace transform of $\frac{2s + 1}{s(s + 1)(s + 2)}$ without using partial fractions?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, partial-fractions

I'm wondering if we can perhaps using the convolution theorem to find the inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{2s + 1}{s(s + 1)(s + 2)}$? I can find it using partial fraction decomposition, but it is not obvious to me whether this is the convolution of two functions?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not right away the convolution of two functions but you can split into two fractions and use convolution on each one and add the results .

Comment: Ok, I used partial fraction decomposition first and then got it.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(s)=\dfrac{2s + 1}{s(s + 1)(s + 2)}$$
With $s\to s-\dfrac12$
$$\dfrac{2s}{\left(s^2-\dfrac14\right)\left(s+\dfrac32\right)}=\dfrac{s}{\left(s^2-\dfrac14\right)}\dfrac{2}{s+\dfrac32}=\int_0^x\cosh\dfrac12t\cdot 2e^{-\frac32t}\ dt=\int_0^x e^{-t}+e^{-2t}\ dt=-e^{-x}-\dfrac12e^{-2x}+\dfrac32$$
then from $F(s-c)=e^{cx}f(x)$ we have
$$f(x)=e^{-\frac12x}\left(-e^{-x}-\dfrac12e^{-2x}+\dfrac32\right)=-e^{-\frac32x}-\dfrac12e^{-\frac52x}+\dfrac32e^{-\frac12x}$$